# RMAN corrupts passwordfile

Tags: oracle, rman, standby, oracle-asm, oracle-rac

please, can you clarify this? 
My configuration is RAC 12c on ASM on SLES 11 SP 4 on SystemZ.

The nodes **rac11** and **rac12** are the server nodes of the primary database, named "primdb", uniq_name is "primdb". The instance names are **prim1** and **prim2** correspondingly.

The nodes **rac21** and **rac22** are nodes of the standby database named "primdb", uniq name is "stdbydb". The instance names are **stdby1** and **stdby2** correspondingly.

So, I'm trying to create physical standby using RMAN active duplication.

After configuring such parameters as log_archive_dest, dump_dest, and so on I copied password file to the standby server and changed init-file.
I added static entry to the listener on **rac21** (not SCAN-address) with service name of the **stdby1** instance and was able to connect to "nomount" database as SYS from any of my servers.

```
$>su - oracle
$> . oraenv
    ORACLE_SID = [oracle] ? stdby1
    ORACLE_HOME = [/home/oracle] ? /u01/app/oracle_home
    The Oracle base has been set to /u01/app/oracle_base
$>sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL>startup nomount pfile='/tmp/initstdby1.ora'
```

after that i perform the following:

```
$> rman target sys/q1@primdb auxiliary sys/q1@stdby1
```

> connected to target database: PRIMDB (DBID=636407725)
>     connected to auxiliary database: PRIMDB (not mounted)

```
$>duplicate target database for standby from active database nofilenamecheck;
```

And on the step of executing memory script (sorry, i can't paste all RMAN output here) a wild error appears

> RMAN-00571:
>   =========================================================== RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS
>   =============== RMAN-00571: =========================================================== RMAN-00554: initialization of internal recovery manager package failed
>   RMAN-04006: error from auxiliary database: ORA-00600: internal error
>   code, arguments: [kzsrsea_ext], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
>   [], []
>   ------------------------------------------->

After that i'm not able to connect to this nomount database using sql*Net,
the same error ORA-600 appears  .
The only way to connect to this database instance is to connect locally

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

And the interesting moment - if i copy the passwordfile again from the primary database to standby, i can connect to this standby database instance.

So i think, that RMAN changes my passwordfile on the standby server. I searched for the same error on MOS ([Doc ID:1136834.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=552003341883876&id=1136834.1&_adf.ctrl-state=2jqjwhc8j_228)), but they suggest to use backups as the workaround, which is not suitable for me.

Any help would be much appreciated..